# extract values from list with the help of another list with condition in python

Tags: python

Extract items from the list with comes in between another list items

```
a = [4,8]
b = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
```

I want to extract values from b list which comes in between 4 and 8 values of list a ?

Result should be

```
b = [5,6,7]
```

Comment: `a` always have 2 values only?

Comment: You might want to add another example. when you say comes in between, are you using 4 and 8 as "indexes" or "values"? For a better example, given `b = [10,20,25,30]` can `a` be `[23, 27]` or a will be `[1,3]`?

Comment: yes ....list a will always have 2 values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use inbuilt `filter()` method.

```py
a = [4, 8]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0]

# If you aren't sure that items in a is in correct order then use min max
c = list(filter(lambda x: min(a) < x < max(a), b))
```

Or use list comprehension:

```py
c = [x for x in b if min(a) < x < max(a)]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
In [8]: a = [4,8]

In [9]: b = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]

In [10]: [ item for item in b if a[0] < item < a[1]]
Out[10]: [5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: You could directly use `a[0] < item < a[1]`

Answer (score 0):

Others have posted answers that rely on ordered lists of integers. However, if you are operating on unordered lists where values can be of any type, this answer will work where others do not.

```py
result = b[b.index(a[0]) + 1 : b.index(a[1])]
```

```
In[2]: a = [1, "a"]; b = [0.229, "b", 1, [], "c", 5, "5", 2, "a"]
In[3]: b[b.index(a[0]) + 1 : b.index(a[1])]
Out[4]: [[], 'c', 5, '5', 2]
```